# Not getting response code on eBay redirect URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, ebay-api

I'm trying to call below link to connect with eBay O'Auth account.

```
https://auth.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=' . APP_ID . 
'&response_type=code&redirect_uri=' . RU_NAME . 
'&scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope 
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.marketing.readonly 
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.marketing 
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory.readonly 
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory 
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account.readonly 
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account 
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.fulfillment.readonly 
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.fulfillment 
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.analytics.readonly
```

But it's response is blank while I'm using same thing on localhost and it's working fine but when I give live servers URL then it's response is blank.

I'm using production eBay account details. Even with same details working on localhost. Also my live server have SSL.

Comment: have you solve this???

Answer (score 0):

### Try to get the url from eBay themselfs:

1. Go to eBay link for Autorization:
   [eBay Autorization page for Developers](https://developer.ebay.com/my/auth?env=production&index=0&auth_type=oauth)
2. Then click on **Get a Token from eBay via Your Application**
3. Now click on **See all**
   [image]
4. Copy the whole string, take that **url** instead of making it yourself.