# how to resolve ( [error] => invalid_client [error_description] => client authentication failed ) for ebay

Tags: php, codeigniter, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

```
public function authorizationToken(){
$link = "https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";
$codeAuth = base64_encode($this->clientID.':'.$this->certID);
$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization: Basic '.$codeAuth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=authorization_code&code=".urlencode($this->authCode)."&redirect_uri=".$this->ruName."&scope=".urlencode('https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($response, true);$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);print_r($json);}
```

Comment: please help me out

Comment: check this link https://www.angelleye.com/how-to-integrate-ebay-apis-with-php-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting `refresh_token` confused with `authorization_token`, because you are mixing incompatible parameters between the two different requests.

If you are trying to get the initial *"AccessToken"* (AKA UserAccessToken, access_token, AuthToken, ...), then you should **not** include the `scope` parameter in your request body.  So your request body should look like this:

```
grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&code=<authorization_code>
```

Where `<authorization_code>` is the value that is returned from [here](https://developer.ebay.com/my/auth/?env=sandbox&index=0#).

For an overview of the difference, I'd recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45330860/10746224) over the [official docs](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-authorization-code-grant.html) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  public function authorizationToken(){
    $link = "https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";
    $codeAuth = base64_encode($this->clientID.':'.$this->certID);
    $ch = curl_init($link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization: Basic '.$codeAuth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=".urlencode('https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope'));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($json);
}
```

Comment: have you pass proper client id and client secret? Check this link https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-base64-credentials.html

Comment: yes, but $this->authCode = base64_encode($this->clientID.':'.$this->certID); i have passed atuhcode like this

Comment: echo 2 varibales $this->clientID and $this->certID and check you have proper or not

Comment: $this->devID = 'XXXX';
    $this->appID = 'XXXX';
    $this->certID = 'XXXX';
    $this->clientID = 'XXXX';
    $this->serverUrl = 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';
    $this->authCode = base64_encode($this->clientID.':'.$this->certID);
    $this->authToken ="";
    $this->refreshToken ="";
    $this->ruName= "XXXX";

Comment: checked cliendid & certid using echo. both are proper

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it if it solve your problem please accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir but still getting the same error

Comment: is it possible to share client id and client secret with me

Comment: have you put proper authorization code in urlencode($this->authCode)? Have you create user token?