Get OAuth Ebay access token nigthmare MediaAPI
I'm struggling creating a new access token for the media api (I need the product videos). I just finally get the "code" via url and it's "new" OAuth2. With this I get the access token and with this I can be able to get the info of a video by the videoID parameter of getItem endpoint.
My problem is this. I need to update programmatically my woocommerce website. I desing a script to get the items, save to a cvs file and import via wp all import, but I need to get the videos urls and I can get only the "code" param open a new window and needs the human intervention. If I use the access token to get the video for 1 product and if I use the same token to a new product then ebay returns me an error like: "The access token is invalid or has already use it" (say something like this)
How can I get the access token or improve this process to avoid human intervention??? or maybe one every 18 months that it's suppose to live the refresh token.
This is my dummy code, this is only for testing purpose:
<?php
$oauth_clientIdfile  = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA';     // file containing appID  = clientID

$client_id = $oauth_clientIdfile;
$oauth_secretIdfile  = 'BBBBBBBBB';   // file containing certID = clientSecret
$client_secret = $oauth_secretIdfile;
$redirect_uri = 'https://www.example.com/callback.php';
$response_type = 'code';
$scope = urlencode('https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory');


if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  // Step 2: Handle the callback and exchange the authorization code for an access token
  $auth_code = $_GET['code'];

  $token_url = "https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";

  $post_fields = http_build_query([
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => $auth_code,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
  ]);

  $headers = [
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$client_id:$client_secret")
  ];

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  if ($response === false) {
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
  }

  curl_close($ch);

  $response_data = json_decode($response, true);

  if (isset($response_data['access_token'])) {
    $access_token = $response_data['access_token'];
    echo "Access Token: " . htmlspecialchars($access_token);

    // You can now use the access token to make API calls
    // Example API call to getVideo endpoint
    $video_id = 'EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE';
    $api_url = "https://apim.ebay.com/commerce/media/v1_beta/video/$video_id"; // getVideo endpoint

    $api_headers = [
      "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
      "Content-Type: application/json",
      // "Content-Language: en-US",
      // "Accept: application/json",
      // "Accept-Encoding: gzip",
      // "Accept-Language: en-US",
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $api_headers);

    $api_response = curl_exec($ch);
    // echo "<pre>*";
    // print_r($api_response);
    // echo "*</pre>";

    if ($api_response === false) {
      die('API Request Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    // echo "API Response: " . htmlspecialchars($api_response);
    $response_data = json_decode($api_response, true);
    echo "API Response: ";
    echo "<pre>*";
    print_r($response_data);
    echo "*</pre>";
  } else {
    echo "Error retrieving access token: " . htmlspecialchars($response);
  }
} else {
  // Step 1: Redirect to eBay's authorization URL
  $auth_url = "https://auth.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={$client_id}&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri) . "&response_type=code&scope=" . urlencode($scope);

  header("Location: $auth_url");
  exit;
}

The code above works if I manually run open the page in a browser, but I need to run this process in a cron job.
Is there another way to get token to get the video info???

I don't know why the downvote if I have spent more than 1 month doing this implementation and all I got is what I have in the script. And also I have searched for the information and I can't find anything that can help me. Also, if anyone has any url that I can follow that would also help me a lot. I'm sorry but it's desperation.

So, you are saying that after a month, you didn't manage to come across  using refresh token to get a new access token?

Does this answer your question? eBay oauth token and refresh tokens

"If I use the access token to get the video for 1 product and if I use the same token to a new product then ebay returns me an error like: "The access token is invalid or has already use it" (say something like this)" - a OAuth access token usually doesn't get invalidated after using it just one time. Are you sure the error message is talking about the token? It rather sounds as if you might be trying to exchange the code parameter for a token a second time - which will of course not work, that can only be done once.

I don't know why the downvote if I have spent more than 1 month doing this implementation...maybe because downvotes have no relationship to how much time you've spent on your project?? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down. You can also hover your mouse over the downvote button on any question to read the basic reasons why downvotes can be given. I don't know specifically why you were downvoted in this case, but you can review your question against the criteria and see if you think there might be a problem with it

Anyway, in common with most OAuth-based systems, if you want to get an access token without human intervention then you must use the Client Credentials flow, rather than the standard user flow. See https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html . That documentation seems reasonable to me - what do you think is lacking exactly?

Hi guys, Thanks to all of you and your comments I found the issue with my code. I saw all the answers and although I was reading ebay's docs, I was forgetting the scope. I can't be able to do this process without human intervention, but at least I need to run this process manually every 18 months. I'll post my code wit the last change to future references.

Why can't you do this without human intervention still? I showed you the documentation for the process you need to follow, to do that.

Hi @ADyson. Now I can be able to get the new access token via refresh token that was generate with the RuName. In order to get the "code" param that this url return to us I need to grant access the first time. It is for this process that I mean that we still need human intervention. I would like avoid this step, but I dont see that this could be possible. If you know how can I get this code via cron job, I mean inside a console with php I would like to hear. Really I appreciate all your help :) !!

I told you already, use the Client Credentials flow to avoid human interaction. See https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html

no man, sorry :( Although the documentation mention that we can use more than one scope, for this client credentials only allow us https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope and we need the sell.inventory scope to get access to media api. I do not know if you know another way to achieve this???

@ADyson, sorry. I forgot to tag you in the comment above

@AnibalMauricio I don't see anywhere in that documentation that it says you can't use other scopes with client credentials? Did you try it and encounter an error?

Hi @ADyson. This is the error: "The requested scope is invalid, unknown, malformed, or exceeds the scope granted to the client". invalid_scope this is the type error

If you're certain you didn't mess up the scope definition in your code then that's probably something to talk to eBay technical support about, since there's nothing in the documentation which mentions any restrictions.

Althougt I didn't found a way to do this process without human intervention, I was be able to get a new access token every time that I need to get info from MediaAPI. This is what I did:

Getting manually the "code" parameter that ebays generate with the RuName url.
Save the refresh token generated and with this value create a new user access token, but it is important to set up the right scopes for this call. In the case of media api we need to use: https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory
Repeat this process every time until the token expire and if so, then create a new one.

This post it was very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45330860/727838
This url of ebay's docs works for me:
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-refresh-token-request.html
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-authorization-code-grant.html
This is my "dummy" code and it works like a charm:
<?php
$oauth_clientIdfile  = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';     // file containing appID  = clientID

$client_id = $oauth_clientIdfile;
$oauth_secretIdfile  = 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB';   // file containing certID = clientSecret
$client_secret = $oauth_secretIdfile;
$redirect_uri = 'https://www.example.com/callback.php';
$response_type = 'code';
$scope = 'https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory';
$token_url = "https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  // Step 2: Handle the callback and exchange the authorization code for an access token
  $auth_code = $_GET['code'];

  $post_fields = http_build_query([
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => $auth_code,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
  ]);

  $headers = [
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$client_id:$client_secret")
  ];

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  if ($response === false) {
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
  }

  curl_close($ch);

  $response_data = json_decode($response, true);

  echo "<pre>*";
  print_r($response_data);
  echo "*</pre>";


  if (isset($response_data['access_token'])) {
    $access_token = $response_data['access_token'];
    echo "Access Token: " . htmlspecialchars($access_token);

    // You can now use the access token to make API calls
    // Example API call to getVideo endpoint
    $video_id = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'; // Replace with your actual video ID
    $api_url = "https://apim.ebay.com/commerce/media/v1_beta/video/$video_id"; // getVideo endpoint

    $api_headers = [
      "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
      "Content-Type: application/json",
      // "Content-Language: en-US",
      // "Accept: application/json",
      // "Accept-Encoding: gzip",
      // "Accept-Language: en-US",
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $api_headers);

    $api_response = curl_exec($ch);
    // echo "<pre>*";
    // print_r($api_response);
    // echo "*</pre>";

    if ($api_response === false) {
      die('API Request Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    // echo "API Response: " . htmlspecialchars($api_response);
    $response_data = json_decode($api_response, true);
    echo "API Response: ";
    echo "<pre>*";
    print_r($response_data);
    echo "*</pre>";
  } else {
    echo "Error retrieving access token: " . htmlspecialchars($response);
  }
} else {
  // Step 1: Redirect to eBay's authorization URL
  $auth_url = "https://auth.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={$client_id}&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri) . "&response_type=code&scope=" . urlencode($scope);

  header("Location: $auth_url");
  exit;
}

This is only for testing purpose, but I using this logic to the real one.
If you have any question let me know.
Thank you all.
