# eBay API error: Authorization is throwing the following error....invalid grant, invalid client

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, ebay-api

I am trying to authorize eBay user for exchanging token. Unfortunately, it's not working and returning 2type of error for different aspect. The errors are: 'invalid grant' and 'invalid client'
My code response is 200. But, in postman, it's showing the following response for 2 different Authorization criteria

Error for .. Authorization: Basic 'my code'

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "the provided authorization grant code is invalid or was issued to another client"
}
```

Error for .. Authorization: Bearer'my code'

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "client authentication failed"
}
```

My Code:

```
    <?php

    $clientID     = 'client_id';
    $clientSecret = 'client_secret';
    $authCode     = 'authorization_code';

    $url = 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token';
    $redirectUrlName = 'redirect_uri';

    $body = http_build_query([
        'grant_type'  => 'authorization_code',
        'code'        => $authCode,
        'redirect_uri'=> $redirectUrlName
    ]);

    $headers = [
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Accept       : application/json',
        'Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($clientID.':'.$clientSecret)
    ];

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        // CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $body,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err      = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response."\n";
    }

    ?>
```

Same thing worked for me, when I was trying for client credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The body section seems to be incorrectly being passed:

```
    'grant_type'  => 'authorization_code'&,
    'code'        => $authCode&,
    'redirect_uri'=> $redirectUrlName
```

In a working code for my case, here is how the body is passed:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=<code value>&redirect_uri=<uri for my test>',
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using built-in function http_build_query(), which will add '&' in the query. My concern point is the response via insomnia. Whenever, I am trying different method in Authorization, it's throwing different error. Please take a look on those screenshot: https://prntscr.com/1rxmqyv 
https://prntscr.com/1rxmedg    https://prntscr.com/1rxmdxz

Comment: Hello Mr. @
Srinath Menon,
 Response code 400. And response 'The HTTP header field "Accept" with value "/" could not be parsed.'

Comment: It was a typo from my side, not sure how "/" this came in the response. Have deleted the comment. I guess the other possible reason could be the Authorization value. Can you hard code the value by deriving the base64 for clientid:clientsecret and then test? This is what I use for test purposes: https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: I have tried your suggested website to encode the code. Now, it's showing the following response: server_error! Here is the SS: https://prntscr.com/1s1g23a

Comment: When I have selected URL_encoding, then.. it's throwing server_error I have tried on insomnia too

Comment: From Insomnia - right panel - Timeline, would give more detailed stack trace and what is possibly causing the issue. I used Form URL Encoded option for sending the BODY data along with Content-Type set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded , Accept-Encoding and Accept-Charset "utf-8" for test for Header values.

Comment: Built the URL i.e "grant_type=authorization_code&code='auth_code'&redirect_uri='redirect_uri'", and show the response. I appreciate your patience. Please take a look into the SS : https://prntscr.com/1s1m56a

Comment: Possibly it's something related to one of the mentioned points here: https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1239

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Server error could happen. But, still I am not able to solve the issue. If you have more suggestions, please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

The code was okay, except 2things.

Authorization code: This will come from eBay as a Response. We need to fetch the code.

$headers will have to write as following:

```
$headers = [
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
'Accept: application/json',
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($clientID.':'.$clientSecret)
];
```

There Will have no space between Cache-Control and Colon(:). That mean, there will have no space at key and colon. Applicable for all key-value pair.